# Help with marking keyframes for the timeline

Tags: grease-pencil, 2d, timeline

I am trying to work on a 2D animation in Blender, but the markers for the keyframes in the timeline disappeared because I had the express keys for my drawing tablet on. I am trying to make it so the diamond-shaped markers reappear on the timeline. What do I do?
[image]

Comment: If you're really talking about frame MARKERS, and not keyframes, float your cursor anywhere in the timeline and press 'm' to add a frame marker at the current position of the playhead.

Comment: Try going in object mode, deselect - reselect the Grease pencil object and return to the draw mode.

Comment: josh sanfelici, I did that, but the markers still aren't there.

Answer (score 0):

Grease Pencil keyframes are separate from the scene keyframes so they don't show on the timeline nor on the general dopesheet. To see them you have to set a viewport to `Dope Sheet` then set that dope sheet's mode to `Grease Pencil`.